# How to work around opacity issues?

Tags: html, css

It is my understanding that when opacity is applied to a div, computer renders that div on the on top (or surface level) of all other divs (or layers).

With that being said, I am trying to place 4 different divs over each other. Each of the divs have different z-indexes, so that they will be layered one on top of the other. If my statement concerning opacity is true, then any layer containing an opacity will always be forced to sit on top - making the entire picture have an opaque quality.

MY question is: IS there a way to trick the computer into rendering the opacity, without the opaque quality?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="subWrapper1">
    <div id="cyan">
        <img src="images/cyanObama.png" alt="Cyan Version" />
    </div>

    <div id="magenta">
        <img src="images/magentaObama.png" alt="magenta version" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="subWrapper2">
    <div id="yellow">
        <img src="images/yellowObama.png" alt="yellow version" />
    </div>

    <div id="black">
        <img src="images/blackObama.png" alt="black version" />
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#subWrapper1{position: relative;
    display: block;}

#subWrapper2{margin-top: 262px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;}

#cyan{width: 555px;
    height: 555px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 10;}

#magenta{width: 555px;
    height: 555px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: .7;}

#yellow{width: 555px;
    height: 555px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 20;
    opacity: .5;}

#black{
    width: 555px;
    height: 555px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 30;}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hz2xy/1/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wbDS9/2/, testing this in chrome the div with opacity is still rendered below the one without opacity.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. I am taking the CYMK model and animating the four channels to come together in one spot. It works; however, I need to adjust each color channel with opacity and when I do that - the colors become washed out.

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image in the photoshop with transparency and apply the background to div to which you want to apply the opacity and remove opacity property for that div.

Comment: I tried that. The color channels need to be adjusted with opacity in order to achieve the effect I am working on.

Comment: @justLearning Can you simply create white image with required opacity using Photoshop and apply the required background color along with the transparent image.

Answer (score -1):

I used -webkit-filter to adjust the brightness and contrast on the various levels. Took some trial and error, but I got it to work.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hz2xy/2/

```
<div id="soICanPostFiddle"></div>
```